# 2 Excel files with same column width and settings but still look difference on screen

Tags: excel

I have two excel files. All I've set the same e.g. 100% zoom level, font type, font size and column width both 9.

But don't know why their column width looks different on screen (LHS's ABCD header is larger than RHS's ABCD header). I found that although both column width is 9, their pixel are different (88 vs 77 pixel).

What can I adjust to make them be the same?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I might be wrong, but it appears that the fonts are different in the two screenshots, which is likely the cause of this. try changing the font and/or the font size, as described here: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1761-excel-change-font-of-row-and-column-headings.html

Comment: @MarkHill You are correct! Your link tells about the "Normal Style" of a sheet. I found the "Normal Style" of my two excel sheets are different. After I edited both to have the same setting (mainly font type and size), their column width become identical on screen which is my expectation. Thank you.

Comment: [This page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/why-do-i-get-a-different-number-of-pixels-for-the/b7d7608e-22d5-46b9-9864-b97f68fc89fd) asked why the same column width of 2 spreadsheets have different no. of pixels. We need to know how the column widths be measured. The page stated the measurement depends on the standard font which can be set in "Normal Style" (Home tab > Styles group > "Normal").

Comment: if you think it's relevant, you can add that to my answer @SiriHow

Comment: Oh yes^^. Let me add it to your answer. @MarkHill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fonts are different in the two screenshots, which is likely the cause of this. Try changing the font and/or the font size, as described [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1761-excel-change-font-of-row-and-column-headings.html), paraphrased below:

> 1. Activate the workbook you want to change the style of
> 2. Go to the Home tab > Styles group > right click Normal > Modify
> 3. (In Style dialog box) Click Format > Font tab
> 4. Change font to be the same as the other workbook
> 5. Done!

Comment: This answer is correct. Modify font in "Normal Style" solved my issue. Let me add supplementary. [This page](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/why-do-i-get-a-different-number-of-pixels-for-the/b7d7608e-22d5-46b9-9864-b97f68fc89fd) asked why the same column width setting of 2 sheets have different no. of pixels. Different no. of pixel brings different on screen column width. We need to know how column widths be measured. One of the answer in the page stated the measurement depends on the standard font which can be set in "Normal Style" (Home tab > Styles group > Normal).

Comment: [This official page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/determine-column-widths) explains how column widths are determined in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

This is from Excel Help.

**ColumnWidth Property**

Returns or sets the width of all columns in the specified range. Read/write Variant.

Remarks

One unit of column width is equal to the width of one character in the Normal style. For proportional fonts, the width of the character 0 (zero) is used.
Use the `Width` property to return the width of a column in points.
If all columns in the range have the same width, the `ColumnWidth` property returns the width. If columns in the range have different widths, this property returns Null.

Comment: I found the "Normal Style" of my two excel sheets are different. After I edited both to have the same setting (mainly font type and size), their on screen column width become identical.